# mysqli_query works in one include, not in another

Tags: php, mysqli, php-include

I have two include files (fill_boxMain.php and fill_boxBottom.php). Both are included from my index.php to fill in the contents of two divs in that order.

As in:

```
<div><?php require_once 'includes/fill_boxMain.php' ; ?></div>   
<div><?php require_once 'includes/fill_boxBottom.php' ; ?></div>
```

The first one (fill_boxMain.php) works fine. The second fails no matter how I arrange or change the code - and with the same repeatable errors. i.e. the mysqli_query($dbc,$q) fails.

The SELECT query works fine in phpMyAdmin. I now have the exact same first three lines of code in both 'includes' for testing purposes - shown below. I've read lots of the related posts in SOF and experimented with suggestions but nothing works. That's where I found the suggestion for using "throw new Exception()" instead of die() for error handling - and have redone my code as shown. Thanks for that one.

```
<?php
require_once 'dbConnect.php' ; //open connection to $dbc
$q = "SELECT * FROM tunes ORDER BY `tunes`.`title` ASC";    
if (!$r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q)) { 
    throw new Exception("Error description: " . mysqli_error($dbc)) ;}  
?>
```

The error codes I get back are:

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\Woodweb\includes\fill_boxBottom.php on line 4
>
> Warning: mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\Woodweb\includes\fill_boxBottom.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error description: ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Woodweb\includes\fill_boxBottom.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Woodweb\index.php(31): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Woodweb\includes\fill_boxBottom.php on line 4

That 'Fatal Error' looks significant but I have no idea what it means. Any help solving this is appreciated.

Comment: Where is `$r` being defined? You need to show us what's inside `dbConnect.php`

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$r` is assigned in this code. No need to define it first in PHP.

Comment: @GolezTrol I don't understand the logic behind `if (!$r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q))`

Comment: It assigns the result of the `mysqli_query` function to $r. In PHP, you can use an assignment as an expression, and the result of the expression is the assigned value. So this function basically says: `If something useful (that is, not evaluating to false) was assigned to $r, execute this code below`. Anyway, constructs like this are pretty common, also in a form of `while ($row = fetch_next_row())`, but I don't see them often with a negation operator, and I doubt, if you would need extra parentheses, like `if (!($r = m...))`.

Comment: As per http://www.php.net/mysqli_error --- Doesn't that need to be wrapped in a `try {...}`? @GolezTrol

Comment: @Fred - I'm connecting to $dbc. That shows no errors. But here's dbConnect just in case I'm wrong.<?php //dbConnect.php
 require_once 'dbLogin.php'; 
 $dbc = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
 // $dbc is the connection
 
 if (!$dbc) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " .   mysqli_error($dbc));
 mysqli_select_db($dbc,$db_database)
 or die("Unable to select database: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
?>

Comment: @GolezTrol - I tried without the extra () and got a syntax error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Woodweb\includes\fill_boxBottom.php on line 4

Comment: Have you tried the method they show at http://www.php.net/mysqli_error using `try {`? @Banjobum

Comment: @Fred - Not yet. But I get the same basic errors with any form of error catching. I've tried several - including the usual: if ($r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q)) {do something} or die() {}.

Comment: Not mysqli_query alone; mysqli_error throws an error as well. So $dbc is not valid. Can you check whether $dbc is available in your files? `var_dump($dbc)`. Is there a `mysqli_connect_error()`?

Comment: @Banjobum I said you might need *extra* parentheses, not less. I even showed the code in my comment. Slowly I start to get the feeling that you lack some basic knowledge about PHP.

Comment: Also, could you include the code in `dbConnect.php`. The Warnings are indicating that you there is a problem with your connection.  Also is mysqli_query() is depriciated, you may want to move to PDO or mysqli object?

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest: mysqli_* is not deprecated. mysql_* is deprecated. Although I too recommend PDO.

Comment: @GolezTrol I am trying hard to learn php and I probably do lack some basic knowledge. That's why I'm here asking questions. If you read the info I provided you'd see that I copy/pasted the first four lines of code from the first 'include' that's working fine. i.e the parens (and all the rest of the code as shown) work fine in the first 'include'. The problem, it seems to me, is why the exact same code doesn't work in the second 'include' - which, you will notice, is the title of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue is with the require_once of the `dbConnect.php`.  I am assuming fill_main also calls the db by `require_once "dbConnect.php";`.  If this is the case when it get's to fill_bottom the require_once will not trigger and the dbConnect.php code won't happen.

Comment: As you were writing your answer, I saw my problem in the code as per your suggestion. I am using require_once but I'm calling it twice - in two separate includes. Apparently require_once means once during the whole index.php, not once in the 'include'. Of course, that makes sense now that I think about it. Thanks to all for the suggestions that led me to the answer.